# SQL Server case statement with null

Tags: sql-server, case

I have two tables Source and Destination. I need to update Name column in Destination table with that of Source table if Destination name column is null or blank. But somehow Case statement doesn't work properly

```
Update d
Set name = Case when nullif(d.name,'') is null then s.name else null end
From destination d join
Source s on d.id = s.id
Where nullif(d.name,'') is null
```

Comment: `CASE` **expression** (as the `case` tag and [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) says). It's not a `Case` Statement.

Comment: What do you mean by the `CASE` expression doesn't work properly? Considering you're filtering to rows where `d.name` has a value of `NULL` or `''`, when would the `CASE` expression *not* evaluate to TRUE (as it's testing for when `d.name` has a value of `NULl` or `''`)?

Comment: Tell us what the case expression is supposed to do.

Comment: On a side note, `nullif(d.name,'') is null` is a bad idea in your `WHERE`. Stick to boolean logic to ensure that the RDBMS has the best chance of using any indexes you have: `WHERE d.name IS NULL OR d.name = '';`

Comment: Generally case statements are used when there is more than one condition to test for and a separate operation associated with each condition.

Comment: There are a few things to consider for performance and readability on your SQL, but it ***should*** work as you are expecting to. So if it still doesn't, then there's another problem here. Try adding some sample data.

Answer (score 1):

your null or empty filter should be like `d.name = '' or d.name is null`. And you don't need to use also `case` function. You already have a filter for null values.

```
Update d
Set name = s.name
From destination d join
Source s on d.id = s.id
Where d.name = '' or d.name is null
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```sql
UPDATE destination d
SET d.name = COALESCE(NULLIF(d.name,''), s.name)
FROM source s 
WHERE d.id = s.id
```

Assuming `id` is your `PK`, this will update rows in `d` with data from `source` with matching `id` values.